# How to implement CallKit : SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, voip, callkit

Has anyone tried using `CallKit` with `SwiftUI`? Can anyone give me any pointers, whether this is possible or not? `CallKit` works well with `UIKit` however, I haven't seen anything of this sort implemented with `SwiftUI`.

Comment: you dont implement a custom UI for callkit, so it doesn't matter which UI framework you are using. Your not doing any UI related work.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'm only using the native call screens of iOS and set up a delegate to catch events. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no different when you implement `CallKit` using `Swift` or `swiftUI`

When you create `CallKit` extension in `Swift` or `SwiftUI` both are identical. You can also noticed in below code.

So you can refer to Swift code to implement `CallKit` in SwiftUI too.

**SwiftUI CallKit Extension:**

```
class CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryProvider {

    override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

    private func addAllBlockingPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

    private func addOrRemoveIncrementalBlockingPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

    private func addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

    private func addOrRemoveIncrementalIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

}

extension CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContextDelegate {

    func requestFailed(for extensionContext: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext, withError error: Error) {}

}
```

**Swift 5.0 CallKit extension**

```
class CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryProvider {

    override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

    private func addAllBlockingPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

    private func addOrRemoveIncrementalBlockingPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

    private func addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

    private func addOrRemoveIncrementalIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {}

}

extension CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContextDelegate {

    func requestFailed(for extensionContext: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext, withError error: Error) {}

}
```

Comment: Swift and SwiftUI are two different categories that are not to be confused. I think you meant to compare UIKit and SwiftUI.